# Evaluate $\pi$ more efficiently using polynomials of lower degrees

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, approximation

I know that you can use $\pi = 4\arctan(1)$ to evaluate $\pi$. The Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$ is
$$
x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} 
+ \cdots 
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \, (-1)^{k+1} \cdot \frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}.
$$

But I was thinking that you could get the series to converge quicker than the standard arctangent Maclaurin series by using this: $$
\frac{\pi}{4} = 4\arctan\frac{1}{5} - \arctan\frac{1}{239}.
$$ Would that work?

Comment: [Probably useful.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Efficient_infinite_series)

Comment: Yes, this identity (multiplied by $4$) gives a series approximation for $\pi$ that converges *much* more quickly than the standard arctangent Maclaurin series. By the way, you may enjoy [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMlf1ELvRzc) about Newton's discovery of binomial series motivated by a similar desire to estimate $\pi$ more quickly (greater accuracy with fewer terms).

Comment: What do you mean by "polynomials of lower degrees"? The arctangent is not a polynomial. Do you mean, using fewer terms of the Taylor expansion? Please edit your question so it makes sense.

Comment: I guess the asker aimed at getting series which is convergent much  faster than $\sum {(-1)^{k+1}\over 2k-1}$

Comment: Care to interact with the comments, Happiness?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: @PrincessEev, thank you so much for that link, it really helped me

Comment: @SammyBlack thank you for your answer and for that informative video

Comment: @GerryMyerson, what I meant was getting the series to converge quicker than the standard arctangent Maclaurin series

Comment: I’m very sorry for replying so late.

Comment: If that's what you meant, then that's what you should say. Please edit the body of your question so that it asks what you actually want to ask.

Comment: Okay, I did that @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is much information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula – here I present some of the information from that essay.

Machin's formula,
$$
{\pi\over4}=4\arctan{1\over5}-\arctan{1\over239}
$$
has been mentioned. John Machin used it in 1706 to compute $\pi$ to 100 digits.

*Machin-like* is the name given to formulas of the type,
$$
c_0{\pi\over4}=\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\arctan{a_n\over b_n}
$$
where $a_n,b_n,c_n$ are integers, $0<a_n<b_n$, $c_n\ne0$, $c_0>0$. It is common to take $a_n=1$ for all $n$.

D. H. Lehmer introduced the formula
$$
\lambda=\sum_{n=1}^N{1\over\log_{10}(b_n/a_n)}
$$
as a measure of the computational efficiency of Machin-like formulas – the smaller $\lambda$, the more efficient the formula. The smallest known value (in the case where $a_n=1$ for all $n$) is $\lambda=1.51244\dots$, achieved by Hwang Chien-Lih in 1997. This is attained by
$$
{\pi\over4}=183\arctan{1\over239}+32\arctan{1\over1023}-68\arctan{1\over5832}+12\arctan{1\over110443}-12\arctan{1\over4841182}-100\arctan{1\over6826318}
$$

In 2002, Yasumasa computed $1,241,100,000,000$ digits of $\pi$ using the equations
$$
{\pi\over4}=12\arctan{1\over49}+32\arctan{1\over57}-5\arctan{1\over239}+12\arctan{1\over110443}
$$
due to Kikuo Takano in 1982, and
$$
{\pi\over4}=44\arctan{1\over57}+7\arctan{1\over239}-12\arctan{1\over682}+24\arctan{1\over12943}
$$
due to F. C. M. Störmer in 1896.

A "binary splitting algorithm" can be used to compute the arctangents much faster than by adding the terms in the Taylor series one at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your informative, detailed answer. I very much appreciate it.